# Encryption in Meteor

Tags: javascript, encryption, meteor, cryptojs

I have user sign in form. It has about 10 inputs. I want to save that user, random generate password and hash and salt it and save it. How to achieve that? I couldn't find any good tutorial for using Crypto.js in meteor. I always stumble upon account-password package.

Comment: Accounts-password does jsut that, but instead of hash and creating salt it uses bcrypt which is way safer according to this http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`accounts-password` actually takes care of this for you. I wish the documentation of the implementation details was better, but you can see an overview [here](https://www.meteor.com/accounts).

Passwords are verified by examining hashes, so only a hashed version of the passed from the client to the server which is then run through bcrypt.

client: password --> network: sha256(password) --> server: bcrypt(sha256(password))

What's nice about this implementation is: (a) the server never sees or stores password-equivalent data, (b) it's all done for you just by installing the package.

Also see [this hackpad](https://meteor.hackpad.com/SRP-bcrypt-J5mdBojeVfe) for more details.

Comment: So the client hashes the password and the server encrypts the hash and stores it? That means that the cleartext password of the user is never sent anywhere, but a man in the middle can still get the (hashed) password from the traffic (if not an SSL connection) and thus steal the account.Or am I missing something?

Comment: As I understand it, everything in your comment is correct. SSL is necessary in order to achieve security, as you would otherwise be vulnerable to MITM attacks. Hashing the password on the client does not guarantee any kind of security, however, it does let you claim that you have no password-equivalent data in your db.

Comment: Let me add to the discussion that transmitting a hashed password as opposed to a plain text password might not prevent the attacker to break into the account on the specific web application, but might very well prevent the attacker from breaking into _other_ accounts of other applications of the same user.