# DDP Rate limiter on login attempts in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, ddp

I'm trying to put a DDP rate limiter on the number of login attempts coming in from the client to the server. I've gone through the official documentation but I'm unable to verify if any of it actually works.

I've added the package: `ddp-rate-limiter`

My server code is:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    var preventBruteForeLogin= {

        type: 'method',
        name: 'Meteor.loginWithPassword'
    }

    DDPRateLimiter.addRule(preventBruteForeLogin, 1, 2000);
    DDPRateLimiter.setErrorMessage("slow down");
});
```

My understanding with the above is that it has added a rate limiting rule on `Meteor.loginWithPassword` method that it only allows one attempt every 2 seconds. However, given the little information available in the documentation and elsewhere on the net, I'm unable to figure out if it's actually working or if I've done it wrong. I've also gone through [MC's blog](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/rate-limiting-methods) on this and frankly I don't understand the coffee script code.
Can someone guide me through this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly according to the [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#accounts_rate_limit)

> By default, there are rules added to the DDPRateLimiter that rate limit logins, new user registration and password reset calls to a limit of 5 requests per 10 seconds per session.

If you want to remove, or replace default limits you should call `Accounts.removeDefaultRateLimit()` somewhere in your server side code.

---

Next you should create method similar to this one below

### NOTE: You should pass only hashed password from client side to server side

```
Meteor.methods({
  'meteor.login' ({ username, password }) {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword({ user: username, password })
  }
})
```

Then on your server side you should limit just created method.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  DDPRateLimiter.setErrorMessage(({ timeToReset }) => {
    const time = Math.ceil(timeToReset / 1000)
    return 'Try again after ' + time + ' seconds.'
  })

  DDPRateLimiter.addRule({
    type: 'method',
    name: 'meteor.login',
    connectionId () {
      return true
    },
    numRequests: 1,
    timeInterval: 10000
  })
}
```

This one will limit `meteor.login` method to one call in 10 seconds using DDP connection id. When you call the method on your client side you can get remaining time using callback error object.

Personally, I do the rate limiting using a slightly changed method from [themeteorchef guide](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/rate-limiting-methods). I suggest you to the same, because it is much easier to implement when you build app with more methods to limit and for me, it is more readable. It is written using ES6 syntax. I recommend to read a little bit about it and start using it(you don't have to install additional packages etc.). I am sure that you will quickly like it.

### EDIT

We found that using wrapping `Meteor.loginWithPassword()` method in another method may cause security problems with sending password as plain text. Accounts package comes with `Accounts._hashPassword(password)` method which returns hashed version of our password. We should use it when we call our `meteor.login` method. It may be done like below

```
Meteor.call('meteor.login', username, Accounts._hashPassword(password), function (err) {
  //asyncCallback
})
```

Comment: I like the approach and thanks for letting me know that accounts-password aldeady does rate limiting by default. I suppose that will do for me. I will accept this answer as it seems detailed and will work as per logic. However, how does the password flow over the wire in your case? Is it going to be plain text? My understanding based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648775/1745073) is that when you use accounts package, it automatically hashes the password and  transmitts it over from the client to the server. In your case, it's being passed via a notmal method call, correct?

Comment: You are right. I read the answer you mentioned and sending plain password may be insecure. I made a note about it in my answer and suggested the solution. I use `#loginWith<ExternalService>` in my app so I don't store password, but I will remember about it in future. Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Meteor.loginWithPassword is client side... you can't call it at server side

easy solution from meteor official documentation.

```
// Define a rule that matches login attempts by non-admin users.
const loginRule = {
  userId(userId) {
    const user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
    return user && user.type !== 'admin';
  },

  type: 'method',
  name: 'login'
};

// Add the rule, allowing up to 5 messages every 1000 milliseconds.
DDPRateLimiter.addRule(loginRule, 5, 1000);
```

Comment: Try to add more information here - an example of how to split the code into client- and server-side sections might be a good idea. Otherwise, this is repeating information from the other answer on this question, but in a vague way.